# elastic4s search for id

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

two questions regarding searching `_id` field:

1. I want to find if specific id exists using elastic4s dsl. the aquivilent to this query elasticsearch API:

   curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/indexName/indexType/_search/exists?q=_id:foo'

I tried to do something like this :

```
 client execute search(indexName / indexType) query ("_id", "foo")
```

but this yields `SearchDefinition` which cannot be checked by `isExists`

2. I want to fetch all `_id`'s
   so far I got this solution but I am not sure that this is the idomatic way to do it

   client.execute(search(indexName / indexType) query "*id").map(*.ids)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query for id with the Ids Query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html#query-dsl-ids-query

```
 search("electronics" / "phone").query(idsQuery("foo"))
```

Comment: Thanks but thais will fetch the whole document. I just want to check if it is exists

Comment: I can do something like ` search("electronics" / "phone").query(idsQuery("foo")).map(_.nonEmpty)`